# Search for multiple strings in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to search for several values in several columns, with text strings and return the wanted value.

I tried the following, which gives me for one column an indication of a string:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$3:$E$7,A2)),0)),"Not Found")
```

My sheet looks like the following:

[image]

The column `Tried...` only matches `Match 3`, hence I only get `return` back.

I was thinking of making a large if-else statement, however is there a smart way to search for multiple values in multiple columns?

Any suggestions, how to give the search function multiple values?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: @pnuts I edited my question.

Comment: Is it always 3 columns? or will the columns be dynamic?

Comment: @ScottCraner It can be dynamic.(up to 7 columns)

Comment: In order of priority, does priority go to the order that the list in G is found or in which column the match is found?  For example in your picture row2 has both test1 and return.  Is test1 the correct answer becuase it is in a column to the left of return or because test1 comes before return on the list?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thx for your question! in fact, if a match is found it is fine for me. Hence, order does not matter. However, if there is some logic in the order I guess it would be extremely convenient for future users.

Comment: Change the A2 reference to a concatenation of the values `A2 & B2 & C2`  This will return the first value on the list found in one of the three columns.

Comment: @ScottCraner Please add it as an answer, it works fine for my use case. Any suggestions, if order is important?

Comment: To do it by column it would get a little more convoluted.

Comment: Please add your formula as an answer, so that I can accept it! Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concantenate the three columns:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$3:$E$7,A2 & B2 & C2)),0)),"Not Found")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: I am on my way home tonight if I get time I will post an edit with the priority to the columns answer.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of legwork but you could do an IFERROR(IF(AND([Column 1], [Column 2])))